# Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, betfair

I have the following code which gets a list of data, and I am trying to filter this data by 'name' but I got this error:

> Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

### Code

```
 $bpl = 31;

$marketFilter = MarketFilter::create()
    ->setCompetitionIds(array($bpl));

$eventBetfair->withMarketFilter($marketFilter);

$bplevents = $eventBetfair->getResults();

print_r($bplevents->name);
```

### Data/Result

The following results is when I print the '$bplevents' as shown below:

```
print_r($bplevents);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732436 [name] => Leicester v Southampton [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-03T12:30:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 2022802 [name] => Barclays Premier League [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2015-11-21T12:45:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 23 ) [2] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732438 [name] => Liverpool v Tottenham [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T16:30:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [3] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732439 [name] => Man Utd v Everton [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-03T15:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [4] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 5767793 [name] => Season Match Bets [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2015-08-16T12:30:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 17 ) [5] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 19478157 [name] => Head to Head Leagues [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2015-08-16T12:30:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 2 ) [6] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732449 [name] => Arsenal v Watford [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 14 ) [7] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732434 [name] => Aston Villa v Chelsea [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T11:45:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 12 ) [8] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732448 [name] => Bournemouth v Man City [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [9] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732444 [name] => Norwich v Newcastle [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [10] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732446 [name] => Sunderland v West Brom [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [11] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732447 [name] => West Ham v C Palace [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) [12] => Array ( [event] => Array ( [id] => 27732443 [name] => Stoke v Swansea [countryCode] => GB [timezone] => Europe/London [openDate] => 2016-04-02T14:00:00.000Z ) [marketCount] => 13 ) )
```

Comment: So, `$bplevents` is not an object, it's just a multidimensional array. Use `[]` to acces values you need.

Comment: I got the following error: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in

Answer (score 2):

The output is an array, no an object. With $bplevents->name you are calling an object. 
I would do $bplevents['name'], that is the right way to call an array.

EDIT:
Please check your output. Your output is telling you what is wrong. You have a multi-dimensional array. 
Perhaps, after beautifying your output, I realized you should be accessing this as :
`$bplevents[0]['event']['name']`..
you can also

```
foreach($bplevents as $amount => $array){
     print_r($array['event']['name']);
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in

Comment: You have an array of array... so, you would need to iterate through the first array or just hard code the one you want.. For example $bpevents[0]['name']. Or you can iterate like this: foreach($bpevents as $amount => $array){ print_r($array['name']); }

Comment: With this : $bplevents[0]['name'] still get the same error. I've also tried to loop the array like the following: foreach($bplevents as $array)
{
    $listarr[] = $array['name'];
}, still with the error

Answer (score 0):

$bplevents is passing an array not an object. The correct way to call the name is below.

```
print_r($bplevents[0]['element']['namne']);
```

Comment: I got the following error: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in